# Got error when I try to install my WebService on Windows-XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation, services, webserver

I try to install my WebService on Windows XP but receive the following error:

> The installation of
>   C:\MyWS\MyWS_Setup.msi is not
>   permitted due to an error in software
>   restriction policy processing.
>
> The object cannot be trusted

What might be causing this?

Comment: Are you installing it with administrative privileges? (right click on it and choose RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR)

Comment: what is the Windows-I tag for?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel>Administrative tools>Local Security Policy
2. Right-click on "Software Restriction Policies", and click "Create New Policies". That will put a new policy in the right pane.
3. Double-click on "Enforcement" in the right pane, and set the following values: "All software files" and "All users except local administrators".

I am pretty sure it will install now (I would try it now, and only do the following, if necessary), however, you may also opt to remove the file type of your program from "Designated File Types", and set "Trusted Publishers" to "Local computer administrators".

This all assumes you are a local administrator on your computer.